# Link in Icons from ionicons

Tags: html

I'm trying to link my LinkedIn and GitHub page to my ionicons but it is not working. Can anyone help?? My code is as follows:

```
 <section class="contactInfo">
    <div class="cinfo">
      <h4><a name="contactInfo">Contact </a></h4>
      <div class="icons1">
        <ion-icon name="logo-linkedin" size=large><p>Linkedin</p><link rel="linkedinpage"href=""></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="logo-github" size=large><a rel="githubpage" href="https://github.com/hgihliugi"></a></ion-icon>
      </div>
```

Comment: please add the css code also so it's easier to help

Comment: Basic HTML: wrap what you want to be a link in the `a` tag, not the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cover `<ion-icon>` tag not `<a>` tag. What you are doing is `<a>` tag doesn't take any space so it has no width or height. That is the reason why you can click on it so it doesn't work.

Try this

```html
<a rel="githubpage" href="https://github.com/hgihliugi"><ion-icon name="logo-github" size=large></ion-icon></a>
```